# Simplify Propositional Form - Discrete maths

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I was trying to simplify this propositional form:

$$ \{(p \lor q) \land [¬q \lor (p \lor t)] \land (¬t \lor p) \} \lor (p \land ¬t)$$

but ended up with: $$\ (q \lor p) \lor (p \land ¬t)$$

My steps were:

$$ \{(q \lor p) \land [p \lor (¬q \lor t)] \land (¬t \lor p) \} \lor (p \land ¬t)$$

$$ \{q \lor [p \land [p \lor (¬q \lor t)]] \land (¬t \lor p) \} \lor (p \land ¬t)$$

$$\{ q \lor [p \land (¬t \lor p)]\} \lor (p \land ¬t)$$
$$\{ q \lor [p \land (p \lor ¬t)]\} \lor (p \land ¬t)$$
$$\ (q \lor p) \lor (p \land ¬t)$$

I need help to further simplifying this expression, any help will be really appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: What were your steps?

Answer (score 1):

First step, distribute rather than associate $(a\vee b)\wedge c = (a\wedge c)\vee(b\wedge c) \quad\neq a\vee(b \wedge c)$

$${ \{(q \lor p) \land [p \lor (¬q \lor t)] \land (¬t \lor p) \} \lor (p \land ¬t)\\[1ex] \{[(q \land [p \lor (¬q \lor t)])\lor (p \land [p \lor (¬q \lor t)])] \land (¬t \lor p) \} \lor (p \land ¬t)
 }$$

However, I would not go that way.   Rather I suggest the first step should be to *distribute out* the common disjunct.   Thence you may associate over the same operator.

$${
 \{(q \lor p) \land [p \lor (¬q \lor t)] \land (¬t \lor p) \} \lor (p \land ¬t)\\[1ex] 
 (\{q \land (¬q \lor t) \land ¬t \} \lor p) \lor (p \land ¬t)
\\[1ex] 
 \{q \land (¬q \lor t) \land ¬t \} \lor (p \lor (p \land ¬t))
\\[1ex]\vdots
 }$$

Now, proceed from there.